# jquery validate plugin, validating form fields of only current screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate form fields . I am also using jqtree . on click of every child node a section of form is visible to user, which is supposed to be filled with values.For every child there is a form content to be filled. Entire tree content is declared within one form only. I have a button in the form which on click generates json file. I am calling the function below to validate form

```
$("myform").validate();
....
if($("#my-form).valid())
   generate the json file
```

but this is not validating the entire form. suppose I am on childNode1 it validates only form section defined for childNode1. As far as I have understood jquery validate plugin should validate entire form when correct form id is specified. But can anyone tell me what has gone wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.validate()` method does not "validate the form". It only initializes the plugin on the form.  `.valid()` will programmatically trigger a validation test.

---

Your code:

```
$("myform").validate();
....
if($("#my-form).valid())
   generate the json file
```

1. `$("myform")` - Is that supposed to be an `id`, `class`, or `name`?  As you've written it, it's looking for a `<myform></myform>` element.

   ```
   $("#myform")         // id="myform"
   $(".myform")         // class="myform"
   $("[name='myform']") // name="myform"
   ```
2. Is your `form` element called `myform` or `my-form`?  If it's the same `<form>` element, then the two jQuery selectors would be the same.
3. `$("#my-form)` is missing the closing quotation mark.

If the `id` of the `<form>` element is `"myform"`, then your code should be...

```
$("#myform").validate();      // <- initialize the plugin
....
if ($("#myform").valid()) {   // <- test the form's validity
   // generate the json file
   ....
}
```

---

> **OP Title**:  jquery validate plugin, validating form fields of only current screen

Your question does not seem to have anything to do with the title.  There is only one form described in your OP, and since this is JavaScript, only the page that's loaded in the browser is relevant.  Not sure what you mean by *"current screen"*.

---

> but this is not validating the entire form. suppose I am on childNode1 it validates only form section defined for childNode1. As far as I have understood jquery validate plugin should validate entire form when correct form id is specified.

By default, the plugin will not validate any form fields that are hidden.  You would manipulate the `ignore` option to over-ride this behavior.  Setting `ignore` to `[]` will tell the plugin to ignore nothing and validate all fields including the hidden ones.

Comment: my form declaration goes like this <form id="myform"></form> but i guess i found my solution in your explanation. At a time only 1 section of form fields are visible (rest of the other childNodes form fields are hidden)